# Align text without including other content

Tags: css, html

I have a div:

```
<div>
   MyTitle
   <img style="vertical-align:middle; float:right;padding-right:10px; padding-top:6px;" src="/images/image.png">
</div>
```

I would like to center the text "MyTitle" without taking in count the image size, because now is taking it. How can I ignore the image for centering my title keeping this html structure?

Comment: You mean how to center the text without centering the image?

Comment: What's the actual problem? As the code stands now, putting the style `text-align: center` for the div parent should not center the image since it is floating. How does the image width matter with respect to the div since the image is floating it's not even in the content flow of the div. Please clarify

Comment: sorry I didn't reply you on time, yes that's was the idea, centering the text without including the image. Adding "position:absolute;right:0;top:0;" fixed my centering issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can center the text inside a div without considering the image's width/height. *The best practice is to add your styles in an external stylesheet as the following.*

```css
div {
    text-align:center /* Center the text */
}
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:right;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:6px;

    position:absolute;right:0;top:0; /* This will exclude the image from being counted in size for the parent(div) */
    z-index:-1; /* This lets the text to be over the image if necessary */
}
```

```html
<div>MyTitle
    <img src="/images/image.png" alt="My Image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
<div class="container">
    <p>MyTitle</p>
    <img src="/images/image.png" />
</div>
```

And the CSS to be applied

```
.container p {
    text-align:center;
}
.container img {
    float:right;
    padding: 6px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not keeping the html structure

Comment: The first thing is that he has already applied float right to the image. Thus, if you apply a css of text-align: center to the div, only the text will be centered and not the image as it is floating right. So I don't know where the problem is???

Comment: So why did you post a solution? I asked for clarification but we have none so far